# unwanted spaces between tables and nested tables

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem. I'm preparing template for html emails, I have some restrictions, because this html has to be uploaded to spamming machine (for me it's spamming, they say about campaign authomatization), brother asked me for help, because he can't handle it, i recently do not work with html and css and I'm little confused. Styles has to be inline here, so it looks bad. Can someone tell me why i get spaces between my tables with classes whyspace1, whyspace2 and whyspace3 ?

I've already tried all tricks I've found on stackoverflow and none fixed my problem. What is funny, when i change doctype to html 4 strict it works, but mentioned eriler spamming machine modifies it to html 5 and problem comes back.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>what is wrong</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>
<body style="background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<table  style="width: 700px; padding: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-style: none; margin: 0px;">
    <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0; ">
        <td style="border-spacing: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
            <table style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;">
            <tr><td style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;">
            <table class="whyspace1" style="border-style: none; width: 700px; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 350px; vertical-align: top; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;" class="ee_editable">

                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 350px; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;" class="ee_editable">
                        <img src="img1.png" width="350" height="393" alt="" style=" padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="whyspace2" style="border-style: none; width: 700px; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 350px; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;" class="ee_editable">
                        <img src="img2.png" width="350" height="392" alt="" style=" padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 350px; vertical-align: top; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;" class="ee_editable">
                        abcd
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td></tr></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-collapse:collapse;padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0; ">
        <td style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse:collapse; width: 700px;">
            <table class="whyspace3" style="background-color: #522886; width: 700px; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0; width: 515px;">
                        abcd
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 185px; padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;">
                        abcd
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in this line: `<tr><td " style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;">`, should be `<tr><td style="padding: 0; margin: 0; border-spacing: 0;">`

Comment: The code in your question is also missing the CSS for classes `whyspacex` and `ee_editable`

Comment: yeah sorry for that. I've removed some unnesessary contenet and it must have left. I've validated it eariler with html validator and it was fine. And also fixing what have you mantioned did not resolve the issue.

Comment: yeah there is no code for those classes. I've added the ones with whyspacex to mark my problematic tables, and the class ee_editable is just for that spamming machine. I don't use classes at all, because it's just html and css, and css has to be inline.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or plunkr? BTW I think you misunderstood the requirement "CSS has to be inline", I've worked with HTML/CSS for e-mails before and you can have your CSS classes inside a `<style>` tag, the inline part means that the CSS has to be in the same HTML "file", it cannot be included using a `<link>` tag.

Comment: for now i don't remember why css had to be inline, but it has to be, believe me. I'm doing this for the seccond time, and first time I've putted css between <style> tags but I think that website, that parses it for itselve didn't respect <style> tags. I'm not sure, but I've tried and for me it doesn't work.

Comment: and jsfiddle link is: https://jsfiddle.net/qzswprx6/